# And Again... MySQL Embedded in Java App

Tags: java, mysql

There are a lot of questions: "How to start working with MySQL as an embedded database?", "How to use Connector/MXJ", etc. But there is no any useful information (neither tutorials!). I mean there is no detailed instructions how to do such things. Of course, there is a MySQL website, where is an article about using MysqldResource. Actually, I don't understand what it is.

Let's finish this lack of any restraint! Please, if you are experienced in this topic, give as full instruction as you can! (what to download, how to add jars(say, to eclipse), some code will be great...)

For example, the following code doesn't work - `ClassNotFoundException`- though I have added `mysql-connector-mxj-gpl-5-0-11.jar` and `mysql-connector-mxj-gpl-5-0-11-bd-files.jar` to the project classpath.

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;


  public class DatabaseWorks {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost", "root", "");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT VERSION();";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            rs.next();
            System.out.println("success!!!! " + rs.getString(1));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific questions, not polls, lists or tutorials (it used to be, but not anymore).

Comment: to  BoltClock: What do you mean? Firstly, lots of articles here are some kind of tutorials. Secondly, if you can help - please, answer the question or give a useful link(I didn't find), if not - please, don't flood.

Comment: to zengr: well, may be it is a good choise, but I'm really interested in MySQL

Comment: Ask specific questions, one at a time.  "Questions" like "tell me everything I need to know" tend to get closed as not real questions.

Comment: Well, I understand what you mean. It was a chance to create a page where was an info for beginners (may be short). Let's close this theme...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, the following code doesn't work - ClassNotFoundException- though I have added mysql-connector-mxj-gpl-5-0-11.jar and mysql-connector-mxj-gpl-5-0-11-bd-files.jar to the project classpath.

This is a basic Java problem.  Here's what I'd do to solve it:

1. Examine the stacktrace to find out which class is missing.
2. Use `jar tvf ...` to list the contents of JAR file(s) you think the missing class should be in.  Is it there?  Is the name / package correct?
3. If it is there, you've got the application's *runtime* classpath wrong.
4. If it is not there, you are missing a JAR file.  Go back to the documentation and read it again.

(If you showed us the stacktrace, and told us how you are building and launching your code, perhaps we could be a bit more specific ...)

Comment: Thank you!!! I missed connector/J. Everything works with it. But I still don't understand why connector/mxj can't work on it's own

Comment: why not update the question with details on how to use mysql as an embedded database now that your question is solved and jumps out on google when searching for "mysql embedded java" ?

Answer (score 0):

More informations here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-mxj.html

http://jroller.com/mmatthews/entry/yes_it_really_is_this

Comment: Thank for your answer. First link is not really useful. There is no any tutorial such as how to start... Second one much more effective, but it is not clear why should I use Connector/J with Connector/MXJ

Comment: @Dmitry: then search for it. Only you know all the questions you want answered. You're not going to get your curiosity resolved just by throwing a blanket question out there. Have you tried googling for "why should I use Connector/J with Connector/MXJ"?

Comment: @Joel: yes, I tried, but found nothing =( I agree with you up to a point. There are many experienced people who can give a good advice. On the other hand, I wanted to center here all the information about this procedure for beginners (like me)

Comment: @Dmitry: That's understandable. :)

Comment: Thanks for understanding =)) You are the one!